# Progress Bar Alignment

Tags: java, multithreading, swing

I am beginner to multithreading and swing.I am trying to create a form such as the one in the image with multiple progress bars .I have come up with the code below so far .i have few bars in horizontal alignment but how do i bring them in vertical oder stacked above each other like the image below

[image: Progress bar with progress off different threads]
    import java.awt.*;
    import java.awt.event.*;
    import javax.swing.*;

```
public class ThreadtestApplication extends JPanel
                             implements ActionListener {
    public final static int ONE_SECOND = 1000;

    private JProgressBar progressBar;
    private JProgressBar progressBar2;
    private JProgressBar progressBar3;
    private JProgressBar progressBar4;
    private Timer timer;
    private JButton startButton;
    private JButton ThreadTotal;
    private JButton GrandTotal;
    private SampleTask task;
//    private JTextArea taskOutput;
    private String newline = "\n";

    public ThreadtestApplication() {
        super(new BorderLayout());
        task = new SampleTask();

        //Create the demo's UI.
        startButton = new JButton("Start");
        startButton.setActionCommand("start");
        startButton.addActionListener(this);
//        
//        pauseButton = new JButton("Pause");
//        pauseButton.setActionCommand("pause");
//        pauseButton.addActionListener(this);
//        
//        resumeButton = new JButton("Resume");
//        resumeButton.setActionCommand("resume");
//        resumeButton.addActionListener(this);
//        

        progressBar = new JProgressBar(0, task.getLengthOfTask());
        progressBar.setValue(0);
        progressBar.setStringPainted(true);

        progressBar2 = new JProgressBar(0, task.getLengthOfTask());
        progressBar2.setValue(0);
        progressBar2.setStringPainted(true);

        progressBar3 = new JProgressBar(0, task.getLengthOfTask());
        progressBar3.setValue(0);
        progressBar3.setStringPainted(true);


        progressBar4 = new JProgressBar(0, task.getLengthOfTask());
        progressBar4.setValue(0);
        progressBar4.setStringPainted(true);


//        taskOutput = new JTextArea(5, 20);
//        taskOutput.setMargin(new Insets(5,5,5,5));
//        taskOutput.setEditable(false);
//        taskOutput.setCursor(null); //inherit the panel's cursor
                                    //see bug 4851758

        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.add(startButton);
//        panel.add(pauseButton);
//        panel.add(resumeButton);s
        panel.add(progressBar);
        panel.add(progressBar2);
        panel.add(progressBar3);
        panel.add(progressBar3);


        add(panel, BorderLayout.EAST);
//        add(progressBar, BorderLayout.NORTH);
//        add(progressBar2, BorderLayout.NORTH);

//        add(progressBar4, BorderLayout.NORTH);
//        add(new JScrollPane(taskOutput), BorderLayout.CENTER);
        setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(20, 800, 200, 20));
        startButton.setBounds(200, 1000, 100, 20);

        //Create a timer.
        timer = new Timer(ONE_SECOND, new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
                progressBar.setValue(task.getCurrent());
                String s = task.getMessage();
                if (s != null) {
//                    taskOutput.append(s + newline);
//                    taskOutput.setCaretPosition(
//                            taskOutput.getDocument().getLength());
                }
                if (task.isDone()) {
                    Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().beep();
                    timer.stop();
                    startButton.setEnabled(true);
                    setCursor(null); //turn off the wait cursor
                    progressBar.setValue(progressBar.getMinimum());
                }
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Called when the user presses the start button.
     */
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
        startButton.setEnabled(false);
        setCursor(Cursor.getPredefinedCursor(Cursor.WAIT_CURSOR));
        task.go();
        timer.start();
    }

    /**
     * Create the GUI and show it.  For thread safety,
     * this method should be invoked from the
     * event-dispatching thread.
     */
    private static void make() {
//        //Make sure we have nice window decorations.
//        JFrame.setDefaultLookAndFeelDecorated(true);

        //Create and set up the window.
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Thread Test Application");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        //Create and set up the content pane.
        JComponent newContentPane = new ThreadtestApplication();
        newContentPane.setOpaque(true); //content panes must be opaque
        frame.setContentPane(newContentPane);

        //Display the window.
       frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //Schedule a job for the event-dispatching thread:
        //creating and showing this application's GUI.
        javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                make();
            }
        });
    }
}
class SampleTask {
    private int lengthOfTask;
    private int current = 0;
    private boolean done = false;
    private boolean canceled = false;
    private String statMessage;

    public SampleTask() {
        //Compute length of task...
        lengthOfTask = 1000;
    }

    /**
     * Called from Thread test Application to start the task.
     */
    public void go() {
        final SwingWorker worker = new SwingWorker() {
            public Object construct() {
                current = 0;
                done = false;
                canceled = false;
                statMessage = null;
                return new ActualTask();
            }
        };
        worker.start();
    }

    /**
     * Called from Thread test Application to find out how much work needs
     * to be done.
     */
    public int getLengthOfTask() {
        return lengthOfTask;
    }

    /**
     * Called from ProgressBarDemo to find out how much has been done.
     */
    public int getCurrent() {
        return current;
    }

    public void stop() {
        canceled = true;
        statMessage = null;
    }

    /**
     * Called from Thread test Application to find out if the task has completed.
     */
    public boolean isDone() {
        return done;
    }

    /**
     * Returns the most recent status message, or null
     * if there is no current status message.
     */
    public String getMessage() {
        return statMessage;
    }


    class ActualTask {
        ActualTask() {

            //making a random amount of progress every second.
            while (!canceled && !done) {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(50); //sleep for a second
                    current += Math.random() * 100; //make some progress
                    if (current >= lengthOfTask) {
                        done = true;
                        current = lengthOfTask;
                    }
                    statMessage = "Completed " + current +
                                  " out of " + lengthOfTask + ".";
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    System.out.println("ActualTask interrupted");
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

abstract class SwingWorker {
    private Object value;  // see getValue(), setValue()

    /** 
     * Class to maintain reference to current worker thread
     * under separate synchronization control.
     */
    private static class ThreadVar {
        private Thread thread;
        ThreadVar(Thread t) { thread = t; }
        synchronized Thread get() { return thread; }
        synchronized void clear() { thread = null; }
    }

    private ThreadVar threadVar;

    /** 
     * Get the value produced by the worker thread, or null if it 
     * hasn't been constructed yet.
     */
    protected synchronized Object getValue() { 
        return value; 
    }

    /** 
     * Set the value produced by worker thread 
     */
    private synchronized void setValue(Object x) { 
        value = x; 
    }

    /** 
     * Compute the value to be returned by the <code>get</code> method. 
     */
    public abstract Object construct();

    /**
     * Called on the event dispatching thread (not on the worker thread)
     * after the <code>construct</code> method has returned.
     */
    public void finished() {
    }

    /**
     * A new method that interrupts the worker thread.  Call this method
     * to force the worker to stop what it's doing.
     */
    public void interrupt() {
        Thread t = threadVar.get();
        if (t != null) {
            t.interrupt();
        }
        threadVar.clear();
    }


    public Object get() {
        while (true) {  
            Thread t = threadVar.get();
            if (t == null) {
                return getValue();
            }
            try {
                t.join();
            }
            catch (InterruptedException e) {
                Thread.currentThread().interrupt(); // propagate
                return null;
            }
        }
    }



//      Start a thread that will call the <code>construct</code> method
//      and then exit.

    public SwingWorker() {
        final Runnable doFinished = new Runnable() {
           public void run() { finished(); }
        };

        Runnable doConstruct = new Runnable() { 
            public void run() {
                try {
                    setValue(construct());
                }
                finally {
                    threadVar.clear();
                }

                SwingUtilities.invokeLater(doFinished);
            }
        };

        Thread t = new Thread(doConstruct);
        threadVar = new ThreadVar(t);
    }

    /**
     * Start the worker thread.
     */
    public void start() {
        Thread t = threadVar.get();
        if (t != null) {
            t.start();
        }
    }

//    public void pause() {
//        Thread t = threadVar.get();
//        if (t != null) {
//            t.start();
//        }
//    }
//    
//    public void resume() {
//        Thread t = threadVar.get();
//        if (t != null) {
//            t.start();
//        }
//    }
   }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
JPanel panel = new JPanel();
```

The default layout manager for a JPanel is a `FlowLayout`, which displays components horizontally.

If you want a vertical layout then you need to use a different layout manager or combination of layout managers.

Maybe you create a panel using a `GridLayout`. Then you add the progress bars to that panel. Then you add the panel to another panel using a different layout manager to get your desired layout.

Maybe something like:

```
JPanel progressPanel = new JPanel( new GridLayout(0, 1) );
progressPanel.add( progressBar1 );
progressPanel.add( progressBar2 );
progresspanel.add( progressBar2 );
someOtherPanel.add( progressPanel );
```

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Layout Managers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html) for more information and working examples.

Edit:

```
setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(20, 800, 200, 20));
```

Why are you using a Border with value like 800 and 200.

Try something more reasonable:

```
setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(20, 20, 20, 20));
```

Comment: How do pull down the start button  to the lower left corner like it is in the image ?

Comment: @SamLot,, maybe use a BorderLayout for the main panel. Then add the progressPanel (described above) to the BorderLayout.CENTER. Then create a 'buttonsPanel" that uses a FlowLayout that is left aligned. Then add the start button to this panel and the buttonsPanel to the BorderLayout.PAGE_END.

Answer (score 3):

You need to use [layout managers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html).

Here's a quick example, with a `GridBagLayout` to show you how with your current code but the general UI is ugly since I didn't take the time to fix all of it but only took time to show you what you wanted to do :

```
    JPanel panel = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());

    GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
    gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
    gbc.weightx = 1;
    gbc.weighty = 1;
    gbc.gridx = 0;
    gbc.gridy = 0;
    panel.add(startButton, gbc);
    gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
    gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
    gbc.weightx = 1;
    gbc.weighty = 1;
    gbc.gridx = 1;
    gbc.gridy = 0;
//        panel.add(pauseButton);
//        panel.add(resumeButton);s
    panel.add(progressBar, gbc);
    gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
    gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
    gbc.weightx = 1;
    gbc.weighty = 1;
    gbc.gridx = 1;
    gbc.gridy = 1;
    panel.add(progressBar2, gbc);
    gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
    gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
    gbc.weightx = 1;
    gbc.weighty = 1;
    gbc.gridx = 1;
    gbc.gridy = 2;
    panel.add(progressBar3, gbc);
    gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
    gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
    gbc.weightx = 1;
    gbc.weighty = 1;
    gbc.gridx = 1;
    gbc.gridy = 3;
```

Which gives this :

[image]

Comment: That stacks the bars in the way it is required but how can it be pulled down to the lower left corner like it is in the image ?

Comment: That's why both answer link the tutorial on layout manager. I won't code your whole UI for you. You'll need to learn on layout managers and use the ones that fit best the UI you want to have. What I did is show you that is is possible but there's a lot more to do to fix the rest.